# laravel one route with multiple controllers based on user role

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

So i'm trying to achieve something, that seems is impossible. I want some routes in my application to use different controller based on user role. This is the approach i'm trying, but it doesn't work well. The user routes work, but admin routes return and Trying to get property on non object error in the VerifyCsrfToken.php file*

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'isAdmin'), function() {
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\TestController@getIndex');
});

Route::group(array('middleware' => 'isUser'), function() {
    Route::get('/', 'User\TestController@getIndex');
});
```

My middlewares

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
}

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->isUser()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I've seen some handle this kind of situation, by just handling this in the controllers or even checking the use role inside the routes file, but I would rather use middlwares, so my routes file would be cleaner

Comment: The error message may be irrelevant to the codes shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (auth()->check()) {
        if (auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
            return redirect()->route('');
        } elseif (auth()->user()->isUser()) {
            return redirect()->route();
        } else {
            return view('index');
        }
    }
    return redirect()->to('login');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message has probably nothing to do with the code your show.

But using multiple controllers on one route is impossible, I asked the same question once.

But you could just use one controller and handle the authorization in that controller.

For example:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        //Admin
        return $this->getAdminIndex();
    } else {
        //No admin
        return $this->getUserIndex();
    }
}

protected function getAdminIndex()
{
    return view('admin.index');
}

protected function getUserIndex()
{
    return view('user.index');
}
```

But the cleanest way to do it is to just have 2 routes.